# How to feed Jasper report with nested Java bean?

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I'm new to Jasper Report and need to generate a report that reflects all the fields in a complex Java bean.  The Java bean contains a combination of simple `String` fields and arrays of other Java beans like:

```
class Abean {
    String a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, a6;
    Bbean[] bbeanArray;
    Xbean[] xbeans;
}
class Bbean {
    String b1, b2, b3;
    Cbean[] cbean;
}
class Cbean {
    String c1, c2, c3, c4, c5;
}
class Xbean {
    String x1, x2;
}
```

From the Jasper documentation and API, it seems like the most appropriate solution would be to use a `JRAbstractBeanDataSource` with a `JRAbstractBeanDataSourceProvider`, instead of some other type of  collection/array DataSource, but from the closest examples that I could find - demonstrated at http://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/how-create-and-use-jrdatasource-adapter and http://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/how-create-and-use-jrdatasourceprovider-adapter - I still don't understand how to utilize the `JRAbstractBeanDataSource` and `JRAbstractBeanDataSourceProvider` classes.

The very first example that gave me the impression that it would in fact be straightforward and clear was their JavaDoc example here http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/JRDataSourceProvider.html  - where I've altered it as I thought it should be for my `Abean` class:

```
public class Abean extends JRAbstractBeanDataSourceProvider {
    String a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, a6;
    Bbean[] bbeanArray;
    Xbean[] xbeans;

    public Abean () {
        super(Abean.class);
    }

    public JRDataSource create(JasperReport report) throws JRException {
        ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
        list.add(this);
        return new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(list);
    }

    public void dispose(JRDataSource dataSource) throws JRException {
        // nothing to dispose
    }
}
```

but when I tried that I got this error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: my.test.package.Abean cannot be cast to net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRDataSourceProvider
  at net.sf.jasperreports.data.provider.DataSourceProviderDataAdapterService.getProvider(DataSourceProviderDataAdapterService.java:88)
  at net.sf.jasperreports.data.provider.DataSourceProviderDataAdapterService.contributeParameters(DataSourceProviderDataAdapterService.java:110)
  at net.sf.jasperreports.data.AbstractDataAdapterService.test(AbstractDataAdapterService.java:128)
  at com.jaspersoft.studio.data.wizard.AbstractDataAdapterWizard$3.run(AbstractDataAdapterWizard.java:157)
  at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContext.java:122)
```

which didn't make sense to me since `Abean` extends an implementation of the `JRDataSourceProvider` class - so why is it complaining that it can't be cast to it?

I then thought I should instead have the `Abean` extend the `JRAbstractBeanDataSource` class.  The examples also encourage the use of an inner class that extends the `JRBaseField` in order to help identify the fields of the bean.  Seems more complicated than I was expecting.

I was hoping that Jasper would have a clear way to identify a bean object like my `Abean` example above that would be used to populate a report.  I understand that many reports expect a collection/list of objects being returned from a database query, but in my case the report is just being fed by a single Java bean.

The examples identified above (http://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/how-create-and-use-jrdatasource-adapter and http://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/how-create-and-use-jrdatasourceprovider-adapter) appear to make it very difficult to identify each bean property that should be made available to populate the report.  It has me investigating the core Java introspection and reflection API in order to be able to extract all the fields automatically from the bean.  Is that really necessary?  Am I missing something with Jasper's API?

Any pointer to a different example of populating a Jasper report with a single Java bean would be most appreciated.