# Can Jasper Report handle nested bean as data source?

Tags: jasper-reports, javabeans

I'm new to Jasper Report and am trying to find a way to populate a report using a nested java bean.  Is Jasper Report capable of defining a nested bean like:

```
class Abean {
 String a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, a6;
 Bbean[] bbeanArray;
 Xbean[] xbeans;
 Zbean zbean;
}
class Bbean {
 String b1, b2, b3;
 Cbean[] cbean;
}
class Cbean {
 String c1, c2, c3, c4, c5;
}
class Xbean {
 String x1, x2;
}
class Zbean {
 String z1, z2, z3;
}
```

as a data source?  This example shows a combination of single beans and arrays of beans, both of which my actual object has, but even if I remove the complexity of the arrays, such that only the Zbean content remained, would that be recognized by Jasper Report as a data source?  If so - how do I tell the report to pull that field 'z3' out of the main object?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to feed Jasper report with nested Java bean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30387992/how-to-feed-jasper-report-with-nested-java-bean)

Comment: Not really a duplicate - but based on the same issue.  The other question identifies actions attempted and seeks help identifying cause for the error encountered.  This question seeks confirmation on whether what I'm trying to do is even possible.